# How to apply the remaining props that are passed into component and aren't declared with the @Prop decorator?

Tags: typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I am converting a React component I built into a Stencil web component, and I am unsure of how to retrieve all the props passed into the component that weren't defined with the @Prop decorator. Here is my React code:

```
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "react";

export default function CoreButton({
  name,
  children,
  ...props
}: ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>) {
  return (
    <button
      name={`example ${name}`}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

And here is conceptually how I want my Stencil code to work:

```
import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'core-button',
})
export class CoreButton {
  @Prop() name: string;

  render() {
    return (
      <button name={`example ${this.name}`} {...this.restProps}>
        <slot />
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the ability to extend any prop that would normally be able to be passed into , intercept the ones I want to add custom logic too by declaring them with @Prop and then spread the remaining props onto the actual  element without hard coding 100s of attributes per custom component. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. That is not possible. Web components are bit more convoluted that traditional React components.

Web Component is **basically** an enhanced `HTMLElement` So if you try to spread the DOM element, you get nothing:

```
const a = document.createElement('div');
a.tabIndex = 1;

const b = { ...a } ;
// Output: {}
```

So, in your case doing `{...this}` is meaningless and also `{...this.restProps}` means nothing since the `property` `restProps` doesn't exist on your custom element.

Now declaring a property using `@Prop` decorator is doing two things.

1. Setup a watcher so that when the value of the propety is changed by the caller, the `render` is automatically triggered.
2. Help setup up relationship between `property` and `attribute` (These are two different things. In react worlds, attributes do not exist. Everything is prop).

Take example of you `core-button` component; you can create a component as shown below and try to add `count` property to the component. But since, the `count` is not declared as a prop, Stencil will not be able to figure out if it should trigger the `render` method.

```
// Custom element
const a = document.createElement('core-button');
a.count= 10;
```

As a workaround, you can collect all the properties into a plain object using some function and then use that in your render method like:

```
import { Component, Prop, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'core-button',
})
export class CoreButton {
  @Prop() name: string;
  @Prop() count: number;
  @Prop() disabled: boolean;

  render() {

    const restProps = this.collect();

    return (
      <button name={`example ${this.name}`} {...restProps}>
        <slot />
      </button>
    );
  }

  collect() {
    return {
      count: this.count,
      disabled: this.disabled
    };
  }
}
```

You can take it one step further by creating a automatic helper to achieve this. Use the package like [`reflect-metadata`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) and read all the reflection information for the `Prop` decorator set on your `CoreButton` class and then read those properties excluding the one that you don't need. You can then use this function in every component where you need this.